# React Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, object, types, element

I am trying to use hooks and React context/provider to show modal in my app. But when I try to show it I am getting this error: 
[image]

Here is the piece of code:

**My Provider**

```
function ModalProvider({ children }) {
const [ModalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null);
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null);
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const showModal = useCallback(
    ({ content, data }) => {
        setModalContent(content);
        setModalData(data);
        setOpen(true);
    },
    [setModalContent, setModalData, setOpen],
);

const hideModal = useCallback(
    () => {
        setModalContent(null);
        setModalData(null);
        setOpen(false);
    },
    [setModalContent, setModalData, setOpen],
);

const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
        ModalContent,
        open,
        modalData,
        showModal,
        hideModal,
    }),
    [ModalContent, modalData, open, showModal, hideModal],
);

return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Modal isOpen={open} setIsOpen={setOpen} titleText="Hello from Modal">
            {ModalContent && <ModalContent />}
        </Modal>
        {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
);

ModalProvider.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
};

export default memo(ModalProvider);
```

**Implementation**

```
    const Modal = () => {
    return (
        <div><h1>Test Modal</h1></div>
    );
}

const Home = ({
    logout,
}) => {
    const { showModal, hideModal } = useModalDispatcher();

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => showModal({ content: Modal })} size="small">SHOW</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => hideModal()} size="small">HIDE</Button>
        </div>
    );
};

Home.displayName = 'Home';
Home.propTypes = {
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Home;
```

The only way that this is working is when I use the prop "type" something like **ModalContent.type** I do not really know why is that.

Comment: In your ModalProvider, try adding an extra set of curly braces onto the value prop

Comment: which place do you mean ?

Comment: <ModalContext.Provider value={{value}}>

Comment: I am getting the same error. another way that this works is just writing 
{
 ModalContent
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you saving the component as a function when using the setModalContent function.

That is so because state can be initialized and updated with a function that returns the initial state or the updated state, you need to supply a function that in turn returns the function you want to put in state.

So, in order to get this working you could wrap the execution of you `setModalContent` inside the `showModal` function with an anonymous function, like this:

```
const showModal = useCallback(
    ({ content, data }) => {
        setModalContent(() => content);
        setModalData(data);
        setOpen(true);
    },
    [setModalContent, setModalData, setOpen],
);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing this, in your ModalProvider component

```
<Modal isOpen={open} setIsOpen={setOpen} titleText="Hello from Modal">
  {ModalContent && <ModalContent />}
</Modal>
```

To this

```
<Modal isOpen={open} setIsOpen={setOpen} titleText="Hello from Modal">
  {ModalContent && {ModalContent}}
</Modal>
```